# How to add a string to list inside other list on python 2.7

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I want to add 'new_str' to my list inside another list. Here is my code:

```
>>>l = ['some_str', ['some_new_str']]
>>>print l
['some_str', ['some_new_str']]
>>>l1 = l[1].append('new_str')
>>>print l1
None
```

`l[1].append('new_str')` instead of add a new string into my list inside other list, it has printout 'None'.

So how can I add a string to list inside other list on python 2.7?

Note: the output should look like this:  `['some_str', ['some_new_str', 'new_str']]`

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`list.append()`](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) does not return anything. It *appends* the item in place, without actually returning the new list.

Because it does not return anything, Python defaults this to `None` (that is why None is printed)

You can simply do:

```
>>> l[1].append('new_str')
```